# bootstrap multiselect - how can i show selected value on another span tag not buttonText

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to show selected value like this [(this screenshot is mixed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AzwP.png)

not buttonText(none selected,all selected, 4 selected ...)

This is my multiselect Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#product_reset_btn').on('click', function () {
            $('#product_choice_multi').multiselects('deselectAll',false);
        });
        $('#product_choice_multi').multiselects({
            //buttonContainer: '<div></div>',
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            maxHeight: 200,
            enableClickableOptGroups: true,
            buttonClass: '',
            templates: {
                button: '<span class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">product<img src="/~~~~?~?"></span>'
            },
            onChange: function (element, checked) {
                var brands = $('#product_choice_multi option:selected');
                var selected = [];
                $(brands).each(function (index, brand) {
                    selected.push([$(this).val()]);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?